# How can I copy to the clipboard the title of a webpage on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-12, google-pixel-6

How can I copy  to the clipboard  the title of a webpage on Chrome for Android?

I use Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6.

Comment: When you execute the "share with" function in Chrome for a website the selected app seems to get the title and the address so there should be a way depending on the apps you have installed. For example Amaze file manager saves both in a txt file you can then open and copy the title.